# how to create backup for update tables structures in existing DB?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008, mysql

I have Sql Server DB, I know I can Create thru "Generate Scripts" backup for SP and Functions then I just replace inside the script the "CREATE" with "ALTER", that will update the target DB with the latest Functions And SP but how to do that for Tables structures  and "User Defined Tables" ?

Comment: You can use `Generate Scripts` to script Tables as well.

Comment: You can also turn on "Auto generate change scripts" if you need to get script of your changes, rather than the whole create table script.

Comment: about "Generate Scripts" for tables I cant use it to update exisiting DB It generate script to create new Tables

Comment: about "Auto generate changes scripts" I did try it but it give me error when I try to run it on existing DB and existing table...did you try in this scenario?